# ¿Como Usar Las SharedPreferences en un servicio?

Tags: android, servicio, sharedpreferences

Bueno mi  problema es el siguiente:

En un servicio cada cierta cantidad de tiempo  mando la ubicación y el *id del usuario* lo guardo en las *SharedPreferences* y al momento de querer obtener el dato para enviarlo no puedo y me aparece este error:

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: :my_service, PID: 28490
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
> .serviciosUbicacion.servicioUbicacion: java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
> android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
> reference
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2962)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1553)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'android.content.Context
> android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
> reference
>     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
>     at serviciosUbicacion.servicioUbicacion$LocationListener.<init>(servicioUbicacion.java:50)
> ```

---

Esta es mi clase que uso para las preferencias:

**PREFERENCIAS.java**

```
public class Preferencias {
    public static final String empleado = "pref_empleado";   
    public static final String NIT = "pref_NIT";
    public static final String usuario = "Pref_usuario";    
    public static final String  idUsuario="00";

    public final SharedPreferences misPreferencias;
    public boolean estaLogueado = false;

    private static Preferencias INSTANCIA;

    public static Preferencias get(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCIA == null) {
            INSTANCIA = new Preferencias(context);
        }
        return INSTANCIA;
    }
    public Preferencias(Context context) {
        misPreferencias = context.getSharedPreferences(empleado, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        estaLogueado = !TextUtils.isEmpty(misPreferencias.getString(NIT, null));
    }

    public boolean isLogueado(){
        return  estaLogueado;
    }
}
```

---

**servicioUbicacion.java**

```
public class servicioUbicacion extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "ProyectoFinal";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;
        String ubicacion="";
        private Context mContext;
        Preferencias preff;
        int id_usuario;
       
        public LocationListener (String provider,Context context){
            mContext = context;
            preff = new Preferencias(mContext);
            id_usuario = preff.misPreferencias.getInt(idUsuario,0);

        }
        Retrofit retrofit = new ApiConfigRetrofit().consultas();
        apiAdapter servicioUbicacion = retrofit.create(apiAdapter.class);
        Call<resultado> altaUbicacion ;
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: "+location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
            ubicacion = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());
            altaUbicacion = servicioUbicacion.rastreo(id_usuario,ubicacion);
            altaUbicacion.clone().enqueue(new Callback<resultado>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<resultado> call, Response<resultado> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG,response.body().getEstatus());
                    }else{
                        Log.e(TAG,"no se inserto en la BD la ubicacion del usuario");
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<resultado> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG,t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onProviderChanged"+ provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            Log.e(TAG,"onProviderEnabled"+ provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            if(provider.equals("gps")){
                Log.e(TAG,"onProviderDisabled"+ provider);
            }

        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,this),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,this)
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG,"onStartComand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();

        try{
            if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[0]);
            }else{
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[1]);
            }
            //int id_usuario = prefss.misPreferencias.getInt(idUsuario,0);


        }catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex){
            Log.i(TAG,"Fallo la obtencion de la ubicacion, ",ex);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            Log.d(TAG,"Provedor de red no existe, "+ex.getMessage());
        }
        //try{
           //mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[0]);


        //}catch(java.lang.SecurityException ex){
        //    Log.i(TAG,"Fallo en traer la actualizacion de la ubicacion",ex);
        //}catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
        //    Log.d(TAG,"Proveedor GPS no existe" +ex.getMessage());
        //}


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Fallo en remover los datos de ubicacion , ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager(){
        Log.e(TAG,"inicia la localizacion");
        if(mLocationManager==null){
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: :my_service, PID: 8506
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
> serviciosUbicacion.servicioUbicacion: java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences
> android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
> on a null object reference
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2962)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1553)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'android.content.SharedPreferences
> android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
> on a null object reference
>     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:170)
>     at core.Preferencias.<init>(Preferencias.java:49)
>     at a.serviciosUbicacion.servicioUbicacion$LocationListener.<init>(servicioUbicacion.java:65)
>     at.serviciosUbicacion.servicioUbicacion.<init>(servicioUbicacion.java:116)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2959)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:178)
> ```

Y pues desde el servicio mando llamar un objeto de la clase *LocationListenr* y pues los demás métodos son los que implemento por eso no los puse.

Y ya intente lo de [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558550/can-i-get-data-from-shared-preferences-inside-a-service) y no me funciono.

Comment: y pues soy nuevo en esto de android    y me confundo y me base   en este   enlace para el servicio de ubicacion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535703/best-way-to-get-user-gps-location-in-background-in-android

Comment: ¿Estas cargando correctamente el nombre del archivo **empleado**  en getSharedPreferences(empleado, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);?.

Comment: Si, pues ya que en otras clases lo utilizo de la misma forma que lo quiero utilizar en el servicio, y si me funciona nadamas en el servicio no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te encuentras dentro de un Servicio, el mismo servicio es el contexto, por lo tanto puedes usar **this**.

En este caso uno de los problemas es que no debes obtener la preferencia al definir las variables de clase, ahí puedes definir las variables y dentro de `onCreate()` obtener sus valores:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{


        private Context mContext;
        Location mLastLocation;
        String ubicacion="";

        //* Aquí no debes obtener los valores de las preferencias, únicamente definir las variables.
        Preferencias preff; //= new Preferencias(getApplicationContext());
        int id_usuario; = //preff.misPreferencias.getInt(idUsuario,0);

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{



    @Override
    public void onCreate(){

        preff = new Preferencias(getApplicationContext());
        id_usuario; = preff.misPreferencias.getInt(idUsuario,0);
        ...
        ...   
     }

    ...
```

---

```
public class servicioUbicacion extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "ProyectoFinal";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
    Location mLastLocation;
    String ubicacion="";
    private Context mContext;
    Preferencias preff;
    int id_usuario;

    public LocationListener (String provider){
         Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
         mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }
    Retrofit retrofit = new ApiConfigRetrofit().consultas();
    apiAdapter servicioUbicacion = retrofit.create(apiAdapter.class);
    Call<resultado> altaUbicacion ;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: "+location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        ubicacion = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());
        altaUbicacion = servicioUbicacion.rastreo(id_usuario,ubicacion);
        altaUbicacion.clone().enqueue(new Callback<resultado>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<resultado> call, Response<resultado> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(TAG,response.body().getEstatus());
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG,"no se inserto en la BD la ubicacion del usuario");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<resultado> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG,t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG,"onProviderChanged"+ provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        Log.e(TAG,"onProviderEnabled"+ provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        if(provider.equals("gps")){
            Log.e(TAG,"onProviderDisabled"+ provider);
        }

    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
    new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,this),
    new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,this)
};

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG,"onStartComand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

    //*Obtiene preferencias.
    preff = new Preferencias(getApplicationContext());
    id_usuario; = preff.misPreferencias.getInt(idUsuario,0);

   initializeLocationManager();

    try{
        if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[0]);
        }else{
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[1]);
        }
        //int id_usuario = prefss.misPreferencias.getInt(idUsuario,0);


    }catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex){
        Log.i(TAG,"Fallo la obtencion de la ubicacion, ",ex);
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
        Log.d(TAG,"Provedor de red no existe, "+ex.getMessage());
    }
    //try{
       //mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,LOCATION_INTERVAL,LOCATION_DISTANCE,mLocationListeners[0]);


    //}catch(java.lang.SecurityException ex){
    //    Log.i(TAG,"Fallo en traer la actualizacion de la ubicacion",ex);
    //}catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
    //    Log.d(TAG,"Proveedor GPS no existe" +ex.getMessage());
    //}


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Fallo en remover los datos de ubicacion , ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager(){
    Log.e(TAG,"inicia la localizacion");
    if(mLocationManager==null){
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Unable to instantiate service .serviciosUbicacion.servicioUbicacion: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int) on a null object`

Comment: Revisa como indico debes obtener la preferencia.

Comment: es que la clase locationListener la tengo de la siguiente forma(como la respuesta)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535703/best-way-to-get-user-gps-location-in-background-in-android

Comment: Que te parece si agregas toda esa clase a tu pregunta tal y como la tienes actualmente con el error para modificar mi respuesta, en realidad el problema es donde estas obteniendo los valores de las preferencias.

Comment: listo ya  con las modificaciones que dijiste ya aplicadas y con el error

Comment: Agregué una explicación y la clase modificada.

Comment: Woooooow ya me funciono , practicamente en solo 10 minutos lo resolviste y yo tenia  ya dos dias , solo que me confundi un poco por que donde modificaste la clase agregaste la declaracion de  la variable  preferencias en la otra clase  a diferencia de la explicacion pero si me di cuenta y  lo modifique pero la idea del ejemplo estuvo excelente

Comment: Muchisimas  gracias saludos desde México

Comment: @JesusSh excelente JesusSh me da gusto soluciones tu requerimiento, un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Mueve las variables a:

--Snip --

```
public class servicioUbicacion extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "ProyectoFinal";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;
    int id_usuario;
    String  idUsuario="00";
    private Context mContext;
    Preferencias preff;
```

--Snip--

Crea el contexto en:

```
 public LocationListener (String provider,Context context){
            mContext = context;
 }
```

Luego inicia Preferencias en :

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {

        preff = new Preferencias(getApplicationContext());
        id_usuario = preff.misPreferencias.getInt(idUsuario,0);

        Log.e(TAG,"onStartComand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: Agregue String  idUsuario="00"; para poder iniciar el servicio.